Rider Xaml Preview doesn't render styles
The XAML preview in Rider doesn't render any of my styles. Everything else works at runtime.
Preview:

Runtime:

I have a rather strange way to organize my styles:
There are a bunch of resource dictionaries for each screen in the app, those all merge into the Merger.xaml file which is loaded into App.xaml. It could be due to the weird configuration of the styles, however it works fine in VS2022's preview and at runtime.
Any Ideas?
I opened my project from VS2022 in Rider to try out the IDE and none of the styles that show up in VS2022 worked in Rider.
EDIT:
Here's a something that may be of importance:
Adding an unused style in the merger file allows the preview to render correctly:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!--  Themes  -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/assets/themes/th_MainWindowHeader.xaml" />
        ...
        <!--  Fonts  -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/assets/themes/Fonts.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style x:Key="Unused"></Style>        <<------ Here
</ResourceDictionary>

After some other testing, I found that any save action on the merger file will trigger the preview to be rendered correctly, as long as the file changed somehow. It can be triggered by adding a space to the merger file. More things: It only works on the first resource dictionary in the merger file. None of the other ones are rendered.
Correctly Rendered Preview:

However, after the program runs, the preview reverts to it's initial faulty state:

After correctly rendering the preview I also noticed that it doesn't render spaces at the beginning and end of strings:
Here is the dashboard button at runtime with spaces at the ends of the string:

and in the preview:

I'm still looking for proper ways to fix this, so that I don't have to save a space character after every run of the program. Also, I noticed that only one resource dictionary, the first one in the merger file, will render even after I do the save technique. I plan to make a separate support ticket and/or StackOverflow post if it's necessary.

The two images you linked are the same.

Yup, Apologies! Should be fixed now.
